# scrapy No JSON object could be decoded

Tags: javascript, python, json, scrapy

I am trying to extract the data from a webpage using scrapy... and all the data is inside a javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Globals
var ANUNTURI = [ { "ID": "2750801",   "Data": "Azi 11:16",   "Zile_piata": "146",   "Zona": "Andronache",   "Nr_Camere": "2",   "suprafu": "65",   "Pret": "62.000 EUR",   
    "Citit": "0",   "Tip_teren": "-",   "Etaj": "3 / 3",   "supraft": "-",
       "frontStradal": "-",   "Etichete": "",   "ArePoze": "7",   "Tip_spatiu": "-" },           
and so on... ]

;\r\n    var ID_CAUTARE = 0;\r\n    var CATEG = 3;\r\n    
var TRANZ = 2;\r\n    
var SORTARE = "";\r\n    
var ID_AGENT = "3012";\r\n    
var ID_LOCALITATE = \'13822\';\r\n    
var ID_JUDET = \'10\';\r\n    
var CRITERIU_FILTRU = \'\';\r\n        // judet_schimbat = "";\r\n\r\n    $(\'form[name="anunturi"] input[name="sort"]\').val(SORTARE);\r\n\r\n', u"\r\n\r\n    $(function(){\r\n\r\n        
var setTagValue = ' 0 ';\r\n        
var comboTitle = [];\r\n\r\n        $('#combo_etichete').mpCombo({\r\n            cls: 'mpCombo etichete',\r\n            header_default_text: 'Indiferent',\r\n            interval_from_text: ' Peste ', \r\n            
interval_to_text: ' Pana la ', \r\n            interval_between_text: ' si ', \r\n            combo_width: '162px', \r\n            menu_width: '160px',\r\n            onSelect: function() { // trigger click daca e inchisa cautarea avansata\r\n                if( $('#cautare_avansata').is(':hidden') ) {\r\n                    $('a#filtreaza').trigger('click');\r\n                }\r\n            }\r\n\r\n        });\r\n        \r\n        $('#combo_etichete').mpCombo({'setval': setTagValue});\r\n        comboTitle.push( $('#combo_etichete').mpCombo('gettitle') ); \r\n\r\n        if (comboTitle.length > 0) {\r\n            $('#combo_etichete dt a').text( comboTitle.join(', ') );      \r\n        }\r\n\r\n    });\r\n\r\n\r\n", u'\r\nvar gaJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://ssl." : "http://www.");\r\ndocument.write(unescape("%3Cscript src=\'" + gaJsHost + "google-analytics.com/ga.js\' type=\'text/javascript\'%3E%3C/script%3E"));\r\n']
</script>
```

when i use

```
json.loads(response.xpath("//script[2]/text").extract())
```

it gives me that error

> No Json object could be decoded

I only need to get the first **var ANUNTURI** and everything inside it and put them in mysql.

***UPDATE***

I also tried this:

```
var = re.compile(r"var ANUNTURI= ({.*?});", re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)
json.loads(response.xpath("//script[2][contains(., 'var ANUNTURI')]/text()").re(var))
```

and the error that I get is this:

> TypeError: expected string or buffer

and then I tried this:

```
json.loads("".join(response.xpath("//script[2][contains(., 'var ANUNTURI')]/text()").re(var)))
```

and I get:

> **NO JSON object could be decoded**

Comment: so there is no way to extract that data?

Comment: Regular expressions?

Comment: Did you even extract that JSON from that JS code?

Comment: what do you mean exactly? i tried... json.loads to extract it

Comment: Use something like this: `"var\s+ANUNTURI\s*=\s*(.*?);"`

Comment: i ve tried it and its not working it gives me ** Expected string or buffer **

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a possible way to extract the data, however with current presented code, it is hard to tell if variable embeds JSON or Javacript. Javascript in subtle ways could be superset of JSON object.

```
data = """/ Globals
var ANUNTURI = [ { "ID": "2750801",   "Data": "Azi 11:16",   "Zile_piata": "146",   "Zona": "Andronache",   "Nr_Camere": "2",   "suprafu": "65",   "Pret": "62.000 EUR",   
    "Citit": "0",   "Tip_teren": "-",   "Etaj": "3 / 3",   "supraft": "-",
       "frontStradal": "-",   "Etichete": "",   "ArePoze": "7",   "Tip_spatiu": "-" },]

;\r\n    var ID_CAUTARE = 0;\r\n    var CATEG = 3;\r\n    
var TRANZ = 2;\r\n    
var SORTARE = "";\r\n    
var ID_AGENT = "3012";\r\n    
var ID_LOCALITATE = \'13822\';\r\n    
var ID_JUDET = \'10\';\r\n    
var CRITERIU_FILTRU = \'\';\r\n        // judet_schimbat = "";\r\n\r\n    $(\'form[name="anunturi"] input[name="sort"]\').val(SORTARE);\r\n\r\n', u"\r\n\r\n    $(function(){\r\n\r\n        
var setTagValue = ' 0 ';\r\n        
var comboTitle = [];\r\n\r\n        $('#combo_etichete').mpCombo({\r\n            cls: 'mpCombo etichete',\r\n            header_default_text: 'Indiferent',\r\n            interval_from_text: ' Peste ', \r\n            
interval_to_text: ' Pana la ', \r\n            interval_between_text: ' si ', \r\n            combo_width: '162px', \r\n            menu_width: '160px',\r\n            onSelect: function() { // trigger click daca e inchisa cautarea avansata\r\n                if( $('#cautare_avansata').is(':hidden') ) {\r\n                    $('a#filtreaza').trigger('click');\r\n                }\r\n            }\r\n\r\n        });\r\n        \r\n        $('#combo_etichete').mpCombo({'setval': setTagValue});\r\n        comboTitle.push( $('#combo_etichete').mpCombo('gettitle') ); \r\n\r\n        if (comboTitle.length > 0) {\r\n            $('#combo_etichete dt a').text( comboTitle.join(', ') );      \r\n        }\r\n\r\n    });\r\n\r\n\r\n", u'\r\nvar gaJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://ssl." : "http://www.");\r\ndocument.write(unescape("%3Cscript src=\'" + gaJsHost + "google-analytics.com/ga.js\' type=\'text/javascript\'%3E%3C/script%3E"));\r\n'
"""
from json import loads
from pprint import PrettyPrinter
lines = data.split("\r\n")
anunturi_json = lines[0].split("=")[1]
print anunturi_json
val = loads(anunturi_json)
pp = PrettyPrinter(indent=4)
pp.pprint(val)
```

Comment: thank you it worked...the only thing i had to do extra...i had to extract the **;** from the end of json

Comment: can you also tell me how to extract only the "ID" from that "var Anunturi" ?

Comment: @Omega `val.get('ID')`